# Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]

Tags: ajax, wcf, https

I have tried Google and also other posts on SO, nothing I have tried has resolved my issue so far.

I thought [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx) was going to be the answer.  No dice.
I also read through most of the posts here on SO that mentioned the same error message I'm receiving, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817718/could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-https-for-the-endpoint-with-bi).

My site is secure, https.  I have 3 WCF services that handle my async ajax stuff running on this site.  When I attempt to access any of those services I receive this error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

My config:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ajaxBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ajaxAsynchBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>  
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
            <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxAsynchBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://[domain]/MyApp/Services/CascadingList.svc" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
    <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.AutoComplete">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxAsynchBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.AutoComplete" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://[domain]/MyApp/Services/AutoComplete.svc" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
    <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.Validation">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxAsynchBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.Validation" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://[domain]/MyApp/Services/Validation.svc" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
</services>
```

I should be able to go to "https://[domain]/MyApp/SubmitNew.aspx" and the cascading lists should work.

Currently the "parent" list shows "[Method 500]" and the child lists remain disabled.

When I hit the "SubmitNew" page, my server's event log shows "*Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/51442863  Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/MyApp/Services/CascadingList.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].*"

If I navigate directly to "https://[domain]/MyApp/Services/CascadingList.svc" I also receive the aforementioned error.

---

### UPDATES

This happens on our production server.  Secure site w/ SSL cert was set up long before I joined the company.  I just added a new virtual directory under the secure site for my new web app.

In IIS:

```
Secure Web Applications (has SSL cert)
    MyApp
    WebApp1
    WebApp2
```

I fixed my config (above) to use the correct behaviorConfiguration.

**-- 2012.04.24 13:15 CDT --**

When I changed my config to this (below) I received this error: "*System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/MyApp/Services/CascadingList.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: There is no **endpoint behavior** named 'ajaxAsynchBehavior'*"

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ajaxAsynchBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>

<services>
    <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxAsynchBehavior"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ajaxBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://[domain]/MyApp/Services/CascadingList.svc" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
    .
    .
    .
</services>
```

So I changed it back to:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ajaxBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="clientBehavior" />
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ajaxAsynchBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
    <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxBehavior"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ajaxBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://[domain]/MyApp/Services/CascadingList.svc" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
    .
    .
    .
</services>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine, except for the service behaviors which will not be attached as you did not add the`behaviorConfiguration` with proper name in the `<service>` tags. But this is not causing your error.

Are you by any chance using the Visual Studio built-in web server (Cassini)? Because it looks like you do and please keep in mind that it **does not** support HTTPS. This is probably why you are getting the error. Try deploying your site to local IIS server and check if it works then. You can see how to set up a https development web site on IIS 7 [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx). One more thing, once you deploy the site to IIS keep in mind that the `baseAddress` tags will be ignored but your services will be accessible by their original names ie CascadingList.svc (unless configured differently).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that I forgot the behaviorConfiguration.  This is happening on the production server.

Comment: Do you have https binding specified for your site on IIS?

Comment: Yes, the site should be all set up; there are other web apps currently running on our secure site (that have been running longer than I've been employed here).  I simply added a new virtual directory under the secure site for this web app.  That's all I should have to do, correct?

Comment: Did you try running your service on your local IIS with the same configuration? Also could you please try exposing your service (on production) with basicHttpBinding instead of webHttpBinding with  with SSL enabled and check if the same behavior occurs when you enter the url?

Comment: I tested locally but without certificates.  I will try exposing the services with basicHttpBinding instead.  Will reply with the result...

Comment: changed binding to basicHttpBinding and bindingConfiguration to ajaxBinding (see config in updates of original post).  Navigated to my "SubmitNew" page and my event log shows this error: "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."  It seems to want WebHttpBinding for those services.

Comment: You got the error because `ajaxAsynchBehavior` is a `serviceBehavior` in your config and not `endpointBehavior`. Move it to the <service> tag and it should work. Keep in mind that this test is only meant to rule out IIS configuration issue, this change will not enable your WCF service for ASP.NET AJAX.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "move it to the <service> tag".  It wants an `endpointBehavior` so I tried moving `ajaxAsynchBehavior` under `<endpointBehaviors>`...that was a fail, "_Cannot add the 'serviceMetadata' behavior extension to 'ajaxAsynchBehavior' endpoint behavior because the underlying behavior type does not implement the IEndpointBehavior interface_".  Changed back to `ajaxBehavior` and `basicHttpBinding`, now I get the error from my previous comment again.

Answer (score 0):

I will be giving credit to dmusial for the answer (including all the comments), but I wanted to post my final config changes just in case this benefits someone else.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877669/binding-not-working-in-dual-mode-webhttpbinding-and-basichttpbinding) post also helped me arrive at a solution.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="clientBehavior" />
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.CascadingList" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
        <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.AutoComplete" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.AutoComplete" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
        <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.Validation" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webScriptEnablingBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="MyApp.Web.Services.Validation" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my case with this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
```